# How to pass from one form to another and backwards multiple times?

Tags: c#, forms

I'm trying to pass from `MainForm` to `InfoForm` and from `InfoForm` to `MainForm` multiple times but the error comes up:

> Form that is already displayed modally cannot be displayed as a modal dialog box. Close the form before calling showDialog.

I looked up at the similar questions on Stack Overflow but I didn't find the answer that works in my case.

So, here is my code in `MainForm`:

```
public MainForm(InfoForm forwardForm) // constructor
{
    InitializeComponent();
    forwardForm.Visible = false;
}

private void GoBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    InfoForm nextForm = new InfoForm(this);
    nextForm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
    nextForm.ShowDialog(this);
}
```

And, here is my code in `InfoForm`:

```
public InfoForm(MainForm prevForm) // constructor
{
    InitializeComponent();
    previous = prevForm;
    prevForm.Visible = false;
}

private void BackBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MainForm backForm = new MainForm(this);
    backForm = previous;
    backForm.ShowDialog();
}
```

I need to use `showDialog()`, because I want the next form to show in the center of the previous form. If I use just `show()`, then my problem is solved, but then I can't show the next form in the center of the previous one.

**EDIT:**

```
 private void BackBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    MainForm backForm = new MainForm(this);
    backForm = previous;
    backForm.Show(); // previous code - backForm.ShowDialog();
 }
```

Can you explain me what happened? This way my problem is solved on one hand, but on the other hand what if I want to keep the content (of textboxes and checkboxes) of previous form?

Comment: Do you want every form to show as *a new form* in *another* modal window? Judging by your button names (`BackBtn`) it seems that you want to be able to go back from the info form to your (existing) main form, in which case all you need to do is to close the info form.

Comment: I am curious to know how this loop started. Which is the first one that calls the other?

Comment: If I put just this.close() in backBtn_Click, the error also occurs. I want to know both ways because I need them in my project. Steve, the first form is MainForm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line is completely pointless `MainForm backForm = new MainForm(this);` because it is immediately followed by this `backForm = previous`. Did you mean this instead `previous = backForm`? Therein lies the reason you will get the following exception (you are calling `ShowDialog` twice on the same instance of `MainForm` and never calling `Close` in between).

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll
>
> Additional information: Form that is already displayed modally cannot
>   be displayed as a modal dialog box. Close the form before calling
>   showDialog.

In any case, I don't see why you would need to ever create multiple instances of `MainForm` but rather just hide/show the single instance as needed. Hiding/showing a single instance also solves the issue you mention in your update regarding loosing the form controls' states (checkboxes, etc). I made the assumption that you want to have one form visible on the screen at a time here, plus I had to fill in some missing things you don't show like the private field declarations and the fact that `MainForm` must have a parameterless constructor.

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    InfoForm forwardForm;

    public MainForm() // constructor
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.forwardForm = new InfoForm(this);
    }

    private void GoBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        forwardForm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
        forwardForm.ShowDialog(this);
    }
}

public partial class InfoForm : Form
{
    MainForm previous;

    public InfoForm(MainForm prevForm) // constructor
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.previous = prevForm;
    }

    private void BackBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        previous.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi. Sorry I'm late with the answer. I think your solution is way to difficult to implement in my project. However, I added some code which solves my problem so if you could just check the update.

Comment: So I assume `MainForm` has a parameterless constructor and you are just not showing it right? Is your intent to have only one of the forms visible on the screen at a time or for the info form to display on top of the main form until the `BackBtn` is clicked?

Comment: Also, this line seems completely pointless... `MainForm backForm = new MainForm(this);` when on the very next line you do this `backForm = previous;`. Unless I am misunderstanding your scenario, you should never need to create a new instance of your forms inside the button click handlers.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Main form has a parameterless constructor but I didn't show it in my question.